Battery drains while laptop is powered off
I have the problem, that my laptop battery drains while the laaptop is turned off. I know that many ohters have the same problem and solutions for that, but naerly all answers are calling three problemes, which can't be the case for muy device:

The laptop goes to suspend instead of turning off: Ruled out, because the power LED is not flashing, GNU GRUB menu at boot
Wake-on-LAN is enabled: Also ruled out, because the laptop doesn't have an ethernet port. (Only WiFi)
Old battery: Changed the battery on last december, no drain with Windows 11.

Information about the device:

HP Laptop 15s-eq0300ng
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Kernel 6.8.0-45-generic
Dual booting Windows 11 and Ubuntu
No physical LAN port

If you know something about the topic feel free to write an answer or a comment.
